# Flex item content overflowing when window is very small

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a layout that has a left column of 275px wide and a right column the rest of the width. I would like both columns to be the same height (height of the tallest element).

This looks fine except when the browser window is resized very small, the right column background color does not fill the entire width of the column.

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/3rejgk5b/2/ (Resize your browser window very small)

Here is an image of what I'm seeing:

[image: Example]

```css
.jflex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  item-align: stretch;
}

.left-menu {
  width: 275px;
  padding: 1em;
  background: red;
}

.right-content {
  width: calc(100% - 275px);
  padding: 1em;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="jflex">

  <div class="left-menu">

    Sidebar test

  </div>

  <div class="right-content">

    <h1>This would be the page title</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `.jflex {overflow-x: hidden;}` - will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving the blue item a fixed width (`width: calc(100% - 275px)`), which forces content to overflow when that fixed width is exceeded, make the item more flexible. Give it `flex: 1`.

Then, give the red item `flex-shrink: 0` so it doesn't shrink.

```css
body { margin: 0; }           /* remove default margin */

.jflex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;      /* initial setting; can be omitted */
    flex-wrap: nowrap;        /* initial setting; can be omitted */
    /* item-align: stretch;   correct property is `align-items`;
                              and it's an initial setting so it can be omitted */
}

.left-menu {
    /* width: 275px; */
    flex: 0 0 275px;          /* KEY RULE: don't grow, don't shrink, fixed width */
    padding: 1em;
    background: red;
}

.right-content {
    /* width: calc(100% - 275px);  flexbox has a better way */
    flex: 1;                  /* KEY RULE: tells element to consume remaining space */
    padding: 1em;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="jflex">
 <div class="left-menu">Sidebar test</div>
 <div class="right-content">
   <h1>This would be the page title</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
      incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
      exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
      fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
      culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rejgk5b/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a custom padding and margin for the body and html tags like this:

```
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

There's still a change, but that's because of the scroll bar appearing, so you might wanna add `overflow-Y:scroll;` to the body too if that's a problem. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/3rejgk5b/6/

Comment: The problem still exists in both Firefox and Safari.

Comment: That's odd. I had the problem on Chrome on Linux and it got fixed by adding that.